# Ipad interface builder (xib) problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to make an iPad application but problem is the iPad's interface builder (xib )file is larger than normal ipad with scrollers. So,it's very difficult to place elements on such file.I want to know that(xib) of ipad is always like this and if not ,how can i make it in normal size ?I hope the question is understandable.

[image]

[image: iPad]

Comment: Why ipad xib file is that big because iphone xib file is of the same size as iphone ?

Comment: Why? Because the iPad is that big.

Comment: no the ipad isnt that big as the screen of computer

Answer (score 3):

You can't zoom out in Interface Builder. The only workaround is to use an external monitor with a vertical resolution greater than 1024 lines.

Comment: Thats a very costly solution for creating ipad app

Comment: There are benefits to having two monitors beyond iPad app development.

Comment: Just playing the devil's advocate here, this isn't just a need for any two monitor solution. 1024 px vertical height for a screen is *enormous*. The only realistic way to do that without spending a ton of cash is to rotate a regular external monitor sideways. Also worth remembering is the size of UI chrome. You have the menubar and window titlebar, and possibly a dock. Add that to 1024 and you have an expensive display.

Comment: If you think less than $200 for a 1080p-capable monitor is very costly, I have to wonder how you're going to pay for your iOS Dev Center membership, or for the costs associated with producing software that go well beyond the hundreds of dollars…

Comment: I don't think a 1080p monitor is enough for IB. It sure isn't for the simulator at 100% zoom.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to save up some vertical space - open IB in a new window; you can do that by

- double clicking on a storyboard in the project navigator
- right-clicking on the tab with your storyboard and clicking "move tab to the new window"

It still won't show ipad screen completely, but would be close to that on 1280x1024.

Cheers